# Get 'Element type is invalid' error when developing a React NPM package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack

I am developing a React component package which I plan to publish it to NPM.

I use following things in the package

- TypeScript
- Webpack

But when I tested it locally in a new CRA app (I tested the NPM package locally by using 'yarn link'), I got the following error message in the CRA app.

> *Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
>   object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's
>   defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>   Check the render method of `App`.*

[image: error]

I created a simplified version of the NPM package and pushed it to my repo:

https://github.com/spencerfeng/my-react-npm-package

Below is the code where I used in the CRA app for testing purpose:

```
import MyReactNpmPackage from 'my-react-npm-package'
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <MyReactNpmPackage />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you export `App`?

Comment: Hi @AluanHaddad, yes, I exported App. I have updated the code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue. Basically, I need to export the package as a `commonjs2` in module in webpack.

The fixed version is here: https://github.com/spencerfeng/my-react-npm-package